# Best way to include remote php, with the least amount of errors?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, remote-access, remote-server

I am working on a project where I allow people to download a webapp that is written in php and they run it on their own server.

I have a separate variables file that NEEDS to stay on my server, so I can change certain variables on it on a as needed basis.

What is the safest way to include the separate variable file?
I was trying to stay away from file_get_contents as I read that I would have to enable allow_url_fopen in php.ini, which I dont want to do.

Comment: Why not import the values via a data-oriented format, like JSON or XML? (Which itself can be dynamically created by a PHP script.) Using PHP code from a remote connection would be highly unsafe.

Comment: are you sure this data should be only in php file? json, xml or yaml could make it more safe.

Comment: I have never messed with anything like that, ill give it a look though! Thanks!